# How to terminate <exec> task in ANT after starting server in Windows

Tags: ant, exec, terminate

I'm trying to start a weblogic server using ant exec command.
After the operation triggers the exec process creates a child process i.e starts weblogic server. I wish to terminate the parent ant process after the server startup and keep alive the running Weblogic server.
I have tried using spawn="true" and  task, but it does not help.

**Also I am trying to call the ant buil.xml from eclipse.**

I want to achieve that the  task should start the server and then terminate the ant process and the calling java program should finish its execution from eclipse.

Following is my build.xml:

```
<target name="StartWeblogicServer" description="Starts the Weblogic Server" >
    <exec dir="${DOMAIN_HOME}/bin" executable="cmd" failonerror="true" spawn="true">
        <arg value="/c start startWeblogic.cmd" />
    </exec>
</target>
```

The above code starts a weblogic server in a seperate command prompt. However the eclipse does not terminate the running program as the ant process is not terminate after the execution of  task.

Please help.